# Formly bootstrap. How do I show label with html?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-formly

I am using angularjs formly. Bootstrap template. I am looking a way to show html code I label. Now they are escaped when display

Here is the formly fields

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'awesome',
    type: 'checkbox',
    templateOptions: { label: 'this is a <a href="test">test</a>' }
  },
  {
    key: 'exampleDirective',
    template: '<div example-directive></div>',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Example Directive',
    }
  }
];
```

I expected the A tag in "this is a test" can render properly.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zofafe/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Put your actual code in your actual question, not a comment link.

Comment: any clue? it seems the label text in to.label is already escaped, so even I use {{ to.label|unsafe }} in template, it doesn't work. Seems I need unescape it.

Comment: Please create a minimal representation of what you need, remove everything else.

Comment: I am not what more I can provider, I already put an example on jsbin, it is easy to see there.

Comment: Something more minimal. Either way, you could perhaps create a custom Wrapper?

Comment: @DavidWeng, have a look at this http://jsbin.com/kogepofaqi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks Satej S, I got your idea here, it works in some way. But I thought when I use Formly, I want to define fields in one place, at least I need set label together with field setting, but now you are using a custom template, and put A tag in template, it doesn't work in two ways, one I cannot put random html in label, second, I have to create a custom template for each label with html.

Answer (score 2):

In my case in with a textarea but i hope this help you to made a similar formly type with checkbox that can use html in label

I create a new type caled textareaHtml, it just extend 'textarea' and use this wrapper 'labelHtml' that load html with

```
'<span ng-bind-html="to.label" ></span>',
```

here the code

```
app.run(function(formlyConfig ) {
   formlyConfig.setWrapper(
    {
      name: 'labelHtml',
      template: [
        '<div>',
          '<label for="{{id}}" class="control-label {{to.labelSrOnly ? \'sr-only\' : \'\'}}" ng-if="to.label">',
            '<span ng-bind-html="to.label" ></span>',
            '{{to.required ? \'*\' : \'\'}}',
          '</label>',
          '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(' ')
    }
  );
  formlyConfig.setType({
    name: 'textareaHtml',
    extends: 'textarea',
    wrapper: ['labelHtml', 'bootstrapHasError']
  });
});
```

Comment: This looks good, but html tags in label are still being escaped, <span ng-bind-html="to.label" ></span> shows the same as {{to.label}},  it seems html in to.label is already escaped.

Comment: You can see the result of your code here - http://jsbin.com/kuseqosoro/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the @imaginabit answer:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="checkboximp.html">
 <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               class="formly-field-checkbox"
               ng-model="model[options.key]">           
        {{to.required ? '*' : ''}}
        <div  ng-bind-html="to.label"> </div>
      </label>
    </div>     
</script>
```

---

```
/* global angular */
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('formlyExample', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap', 'ngSanitize'], function config(formlyConfigProvider) {
    // set templates here
   formlyConfigProvider.setType({
    name: 'checkboxHtml',
    extends: 'checkbox',
    templateUrl: 'checkboximp.html',
    wrapper: ['bootstrapHasError']
   });

  });


  app.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl(formlyVersion) {
    var vm = this;
    // funcation assignment
    vm.onSubmit = onSubmit;

    // variable assignment
    vm.author = { // optionally fill in your info below :-)
      name: 'Kent C. Dodds',
      url: 'https://twitter.com/kentcdodds' // a link to your twitter/github/blog/whatever
    };
    vm.exampleTitle = 'Introduction';
    vm.env = {
      angularVersion: angular.version.full,
      formlyVersion: formlyVersion
    };

    vm.model = {
      awesome: true
    };
    vm.options = {
      formState: {
        awesomeIsForced: false
      }
    };

    vm.fields = [
      {
        key: 'awesome',
        type: 'checkbox',
        templateOptions: { label: 'this is a <a href="test">test</a>' }
      },

      {
        key: 'awesome2',
        type: 'checkboxHtml',
        templateOptions: { label: 'this is a <a href="test">from j. lennon</a>' }
      }     

    ];

    // function definition
    function onSubmit() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(vm.model), null, 2);
    }
  });

})();
```

http://jsbin.com/dunuyakiwe/2/edit?html,js,output

Just two observations:

- It's necessary to have angular sanitize library, and that would make the template work fine (ng-bind-html directive).
- The default checkbox formly template has an embedded label in the component, so is not possible to use that out of the box, that's why it's simpler to create our own type.